# The story of Sage Valmiki (Transformation)

Tags: ramayana, valmiki, vali

[Valmiki wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valmiki)

What are the reasons for the transformation to become Sage Valmiki and write the Holy Ramayana?

Do you attribute to Sage Valmiki's forefathers or ancestors good deeds?

Note: In one of the stories about Sage Valmiki (Wikipedia), a dacoit is transformed into a Sage. I mean Sage Valmiki was a dacoit. The story reveals how a dacoit was transformed into a Sage.

Do you feel this could be also the reason for transformation of Vali (Before becoming Sage Valmiki)?

Reason: Vali (Dacoit) was sleeping under a Banyan tree. In his dreams, Lord Shiva or Lord Vishnu or Goddess Durga came and told him to transform from a Dacoit (Bad) to a Sage (Good) person and then write the Holy Book Ramayana.

Comment: Dacoit turning to valmiki is floklore not quoted by valmiki either that he was dacoit.. valmiki is born to rishi. he is brother varuna deva..